# How to implement authentication in Apple TV with TVML

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, tvml

I'm developing an Apple TV app.

It's almost done, but we need to add authentication function in this app. Like Youtube and HBO, TV will show a digit code, and user needs to go activate website in their PC to link with their own account.

This Apple TV app is using TVML templates to build.

I'm really confused to do this, and don't know where I should work on first.

Anyone has any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your subscription model. If its cable based subscription service that allows you access to the content you get on TV based on your cable packages, then you need to use Adobe's service called Adobe Pass. More details on adobepass can be found here:
http://www.adobe.com/marketing-cloud/primetime-tv-platform/authentication.html

Advantage of AdobePass on TvOS devices is that it allows for single sign on across different apps and once authenticated, the user doesn't need to go through authentication across all apps using AdobePass.

If its something similar to HBO Now, YouTube, Hulu, Netflix, etc, which are standalone subscriptions and not tied to cable packages, then you can directly have a Login ViewController in the TvOS app that communicates with your backend and authenticates the User.